# find a point closest to other points

Tags: algorithm

Given N points(in 2D) with x and y coordinates. You have to find a point P (in N given points) such that the sum of distances from other(N-1) points to P is minimum.

for ex. N points given p1(x1,y1),p2(x2,y2) ......  pN(xN,yN).
we have find a point P among p1 , p2 .... PN whose sum of distances from all other points is minimum.

I used brute force approach , but I need a better approach. I also tried by finding median, mean etc. but it is not working for all cases.

then I came up with an idea that I would treat X as a vertices of a polygon and find centroid of this polygon, and then I will choose a point from Y nearest to the centroid. But I'm not sure whether centroid minimizes sum of its distances to the vertices of polygon, so I'm not sure whether this is a good way? Is there any algorithm for solving this problem?

Comment: an optimization for the brute force approach would be to calculate the distance squared instead of the distance. This is because calculating the square root is a very expensive operation

Comment: @KshitijMehta optimizing the sum of the squared distances is not the same as optimizing the sum of the distances.

Comment: Hey coder, I believe I've come up with an algorithm to address this problem. It's pretty complicated, and it'll probably be a few days before I can post a decent explanation as an answer. Let me know if you're still interested...

Comment: For now, I'll drop this hint...it involves binning the points into a grid, and iteratively dividing up the cells into smaller cells :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your points are nicely distributed and if there are so many of them that brute force (calculating the total distance from each point to every other point) is unappealing the following might give you a good enough answer.  By 'nicely distributed' I mean (approximately) uniformly or (approximately) randomly and without marked clustering in multiple locations.

Create a uniform `k*k` grid, where `k` is an odd integer, across your space.  If your points are nicely distributed the one which you are looking for is (probably) in the central cell of this grid.  For all the other cells in the grid count the number of points in each cell and approximate the average position of the points in each cell (either use the cell centre or calculate the average `(x,y)` for points in the cell).

For each point in the central cell, compute the distance to every other point in the central cell, and the weighted average distance to the points in the other cells.  This will, of course, be the distance from the point to the 'average' position of points in the other cells, weighted by the number of points in the other cells.

You'll have to juggle the increased accuracy of higher values for `k` against the increased computational load and figure out what works best for your points.  If the distribution of points across cells is far from uniform then this approach may not be suitable.

This sort of approach is quite widely used in large-scale simulations where points have properties, such as gravity and charge, which operate over distances.  Whether it suits your needs, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

The point in consideration is known as the Geometric Median

The centroid or center of mass, defined similarly to the geometric median as minimizing the sum of the squares of the distances to each sample, can be found by a simple formula — its coordinates are the averages of the coordinates of the samples but no such formula is known for the geometric median, and it has been shown that no explicit formula, nor an exact algorithm involving only arithmetic operations and kth roots can exist in general.

Comment: We all know how to use Google and Wikipedia. The asker is looking for explanations.

Comment: I just wanted to tell the asker that this is a well understood problem and what is it's current status. 
I have edited the answer to make it laconic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but when you calculate the minimum spanning tree the sum from any point to any other point from the tree is minimum.

Comment: You need to minimize the summar distance from a single point to all others. Minimum spanning tree will calculate the minimum sum of distances required to build edges that make it possible to get from any point to any other. This is not what the OP is asking for.